# CGRectContainsRect Not Working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cgrect

I'm having problems with this method.  I have two rectangles that are obviously contained within each other.(I've even graphed their coordinates manually to make sure.)  When I use CGRectContainsRect to compare these two rectangles, it returns false.  For the life of me, I have tried everything, scoured the net, and I can't find an answer to this problem.  Anyone have any idea why?  I've included the values for the CGRects when I debug to show that they are definitely within each other.

```
-(bool)checkBoundingBox {
    bool returnItem = YES;

    //Checks for sprite interaction
    for (int i = 0; i < [arrGameItems count]; i++) {
        CGRect rect2 = [[self getChildByTag:1] boundingBox];
        CGRect rect1 = [[self getChildByTag:3] boundingBox];

        //        rect1 = CGRectStandardize(rect1);
        //        rect2 = CGRectStandardize(rect2);

        if (CGRectContainsRect(rect2, rect1)) {
            CCLOG(@"removed child b*&ch");
            [self removeChildByTag:[arrGameItems count] cleanup:YES];
            returnItem = NO;
        }
    }   

    CCLOG(@"g-dammit");    
    return returnItem;
}
```

rect1
origin x = 141 y = 76, height = 25, width = 25

rect2
origin x = 127 y = 91, height = 25, width = 25

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`CGRectContainsRect()` checks if one rectangle completely encompasses another, not just if they intersect. From your coordinates, the rectangles don't contain each other, but just intersect. You're looking for `CGRectIntersectsRect()`.

Comment: Thank you.  That did it.  I had tried that in the past, but it didn't work then.  Then again, I've corrected some logic mistakes since then.

Comment: @itia Ferber thanks for editing my answer.. I was on my phone that's why lots of mistakes

Answer (score 0):

rect1 does not contain rect2 in your example.

Rect 1 x coordinates span from 141 to 166.
Rect 2 x coordinates span from 127 to 152.

Therefor, rect2 is not contained within rect1 (because rect2 exists within x coordinates 127-140, and rect1 does not exist in those coordinates).

Comment: recheck your math. rect1 is 141-166 and rect2 is 127-152

Comment: true, i adjusted my response, but the reasoning is still the same. the fact alone that rect2 exists at 127 and rect1 doesn't means that rect2 can't be inside rect1.