# Check for overlapping objects on ViewController

Tags: objective-c, object, ios7, uiview

How can programmatically check if 2 objects are overlapping on my `UIViewController`? I am using this method to randomly move the objects around the `UIView`.

```
CGFloat x = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.container.bounds.size.width);
CGFloat y = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.container.bounds.size.height);

CGPoint squarePostion = CGPointMake(x, y);
_button.center = squarePostion;
```

I have 3 objects I am moving around using this fragment of code. Sometimes they overlap each other, which is a problem. Is there anyway I can check if the objects are overlapping each other before I make them visible?
 Thanks guys!

Comment: Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247919/check-if-cgrect-is-contained-within-another-transformed-rect

Answer (score 4):

You can use `CGRectIntersectsRect` to check if two views' frames are intersecting.

You would do it like this:

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(view1.frame, view2.frame)) {
  //The two views are "overlapping"
}
```

Find more information here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectIntersectsRect